# Role names are case sensitive in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, roles, case-sensitive

Whoever made role names case sensitive is just evil.

I killed a couple of hours trying to figure out why rake commands did not work from the DOS command line in Windows. The error kept saying that role 'Michael' did not exist when I knew perfectly well that I had created it.

Adding insult to injury, the psql command -c "CREATE ROLE Michael ..." created the role alright, but in all lower case.

Answer (score 2):

I finally used pgAdmin to change the first letter of the role to uppercase 'M' and then all my commands worked as my Windows user name was passed into the various processes.

Designers -- pay attention to what you're doing! There's no reason for role names to be case sensitive.

Comment: `and then all my commands worked as my Windows user name was passed into the various processes.` which commands? which processes? (did these use some kind of ORM ?)

Comment: Commands related to postgres, including dropdb or rails commands like rake db:drop, db:reset.

Comment: The point is: role names follow the same case-logic as table names or column names. To enforce case-sensitive matching you (or your ORM logic) can use double quotes. Generally, it is considered a bad idea to use case-significant names for database objects. Particilurly if middleware (*somtines*) automagically quotes identifiers.

Comment: I want to use commandline to do the same. @vbsql7 have you found a way to do so ? Since I want to put role creation in a script later using it via pgAdmin is not an option for me.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to keep your role names in lower case... because that is what Postgres will create and try to use.

Comment: that advice is useless for Windows users. Postgress will use the login as user, so if the Windows username is cased, you're screwed unless you remember to double-quote the role when you create it. `create user "MyWindowsLogon" with login superuser;` will do the right thing.