# The error "role ... does not exist", What to do?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs

How to fix the error below? I'm trying to connect to the Postgres database using NestJS. I have a Postgres user registered in the `.env` file, different from the name of my Linux account, but Postgres is trying to connect as my Linux account. Nevertheless, in Postgres, I created the "Stell" role and gave it superuser rights.

```
    [[Nest] 18553 - 01.05.2023, 22:07:19 ERROR [Exception Handler] role "Stell" does not exist
error: role "Stell" does not exist
    in Parser.parser Error message (/home/Steel/Documents/WebStormProject/spotify/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
in Parser.handlePacket (/home/Steel/Documents/WebStormProject/spotify/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:188:21)
in Parser.parse (/home/Steel/Documents/WebStormProject/spotify/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:103:30)
    in the socket.<anonymous> (/home/Steel/Documents/WebStormProject/spotify/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
in Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
in addChunk (node:internal/threads/readable:324:12)
in readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
in the socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
when reading TCP.on Stream (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

typeorm.module.ts

```
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule as NestTypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
    imports: [
        NestTypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: 'postgres',
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
            username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
            entities: ['dist/entities/**/*.entity.js'],
            synchronize: true,
        }),
    ],
})
export class TypeOrmModule {}
```

Comment: You need to create the role before using it. You say you created it, the error indicates otherwise. Are you sure you created it with that exact spelling and on that Postgres instance?

Comment: @tadman Yes. I entered this command: CREATE ROLE username Stell;

Comment: @tadman But why use the "Stell" role? I didn't mention it anywhere.

Comment: because of the error message.

Comment: You configured it somewhere, whether you realize it or not.

Comment: @tadman In the NESTJS app?

Comment: Presumably. I can't see *any* code, I can only speculate. `git grep` is good at finding stuff like this, if not the "Search all files" option in your editor.

Comment: @tadman Added the db connection code

Comment: Take a peek in your `.env` under `DB_USERNAME`.

Comment: @tadman DB_USERNAME="postgres"

Comment: you need to create role in postgres. very your `.env` as well

Comment: @arslion psql postgres -U postgres, CREATE ROLE postgres Right?

Comment: Try lowercase `stell` - [that's the name you likely created](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638358/role-names-are-case-sensitive-in-postgres, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602509/how-do-i-create-postgres-case-sensitive-role-from-windows-terminal, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694518/how-can-i-create-a-capitalized-postgres-role-name

Comment: Your question is not quite clear on what the names actually are. What is the "*Postgres user registered in the .env file*", what is the "*name of my Linux account*", and is "*the "Stell" role [I created]*" one of those or a third one? Which of them do you actually **want** to use?

Comment: "I have a Postgres user registered in the .env file, different from the name of my Linux account, but Postgres is trying to connect as my Linux account."   Then something is wrong with your configuration.  Rather than creating random superuser accounts you don't want, figure out what is wrong and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not create role `"Stell"`. PostgreSQL will fold identifiers to lower case unless you double quote them. So try:

```
CREATE ROLE "Stell" LOGIN PASSWORD 'whatever';
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE name_of_db TO "Stell";
```

Get rid of the user you created, which is probably `stell`. Don't ever use a superuser with your application.