# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] role "" does not exist (postgresql db through docker)

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs, typeorm, roles

i am having trouble connecting to my database that runs on a docker container through nestJS App.
i saw a similar question was asked a few weeks ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76149956/the-error-role-does-not-exist-what-to-do), but the solution does not work for me...

I get the following error:

```
[Nest] 4930  - 05/23/2023, 2:47:43 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)...
error: role "test" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/user/factor_app/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/user/factor_app/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:188:21)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/user/factor_app/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:103:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/factor_app/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

Here is my TypeOrm impport in my app.module file (main module file):

```
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        username: 'test',
        password: 'whatever',
        database: 'mydatabase',
        entities: ['src/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: true}),
     // other modules...
    ],
```

Here is my sql script:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;

\c mydatabase
CREATE ROLE "test" LOGIN PASSWORD 'whatever';
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE mydatabase TO "test";

CREATE TABLE video_subs (
  wallet VARCHAR(42),
  video TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (wallet, video)
);

INSERT INTO video_subs(wallet, video) VALUES 
('0x12345', 'video1'),
('0x23456', 'video2'),
('0x34567', 'video3'),
('0x45678', 'video4'),

('0x56789', 'video2'),
('0x67890', 'video2'),
('0x78901', 'video2'),
('0x89012', 'video3'),
('0x90123', 'video3'),
('0x01234', 'video4'),
('0x12345', 'video2'),
('0x23456', 'video1'),
('0x34567', 'video1'),
('0x45678', 'video2'),
('0x56789', 'video1'),
('0x67890', 'video1'),
('0x78901', 'video4'),
('0x89012', 'video2'),
('0x90123', 'video2'),
('0x01234', 'video2');
```

And here is how I create my database through a bash script:

```
source /Users/name/factor_app/app/server/.env
docker rm -f my_postgres;
docker run --name my_postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD -p 5432:5432 -v /Users/name/factor_app/app/server/database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql -d postgres
sleep 2;
# docker exec -it my_postgres psql -h localhost -U postgres -d mydatabase
docker exec -it -e PGPASSWORD='whatever' my_postgres psql -h localhost -U test -d mydatabase
```

At first, I just created a user with name $DB_USER stored in my .env, but i created another one named 'test' to make some tests.

I have noticed that when I run `psql -h localhost -U test -d mydatabase` in my machine, it says the db does not exist. The issue is that the db is located in the docker container, so i have to execute a shell inside the docker container via this command `docker exec -it my_postgres bash`, and then, the previous command works fine, and I can either connect as 'test' or as $DB_USER.
I feel like my issue comes from this, so I tried with `host: 'host.docker.internal'`
but it did not work either... so I am just starting to feel desperate

Do anyone have a solution for this ? PLease feel free to ask for any clarification or more log if needed. Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried using the container's IP address? You can get it using `docker inspect my_postgres`, then `docker exec -it my_postgres psql -h  1.1.1.1  -U postgres -d mydatabase`

Comment: I tried that but it did not work... I found out the ip address  to be 172.17.0.2 and I tried to replace this as my host, but i got a timeout error:
`[Nest] 9157  - 05/23/2023, 5:55:17 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.17.0.2:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)`

Answer (score 1):

MY SOLUTION(macOS):

```
$ brew services stop postgresql@14
```

I had a similar problem. NestJS app running locally and the Postgres database on Docker container.

```
[Nest] 22128  - 10/25/2023, 3:10:25 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] role "postgres" does not exist
error: role "postgres" does not exist
```

I had postgres running on the background locally without realizing it.
To check:

```
$ ps aux | grep postgres
```

or the port you are indicating

```
$ lsof -i :5432
```

For me, I had 3 different proccess running at port 5432. One of them was the docker that I wanted, other two had to be disabled.
Then, stop postgres running locally:

```
$ brew services stop postgresql@14
```

If I try this command again:

```
$ lsof -i :5432
```

Only one proccess runing, which is the wanted one, the docker.